# Can't regenerate model code: default method are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above

Tags: java, eclipse, e4, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have an emf model with a bunch of entities. I've manually added a couple of `default` methods to one of the generated interfaces. Now I can't regenerate model code for this entity. Error says "*default method are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above*". I have specified ***Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8*** in the manifest for the plugin with the model. I have specified ***Compliance level: 8*** in the properties of the `.genmodel` root. **`Project properties -> java compiler`** is set to use compliance with 1.8. Java build path uses JRE 1.8. But still I keep getting this error. Did I miss something? I use Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)